# react url appears blank

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have the following react router:

```
    <Router history={browserHistory}>
        <Route path="login" component={LoginPage} onEnter={redirectHome}/>
        <Route path="app" component={App} onEnter={requireAuth}>
          <IndexRoute component={DashboardPage}/>
          <Route path="accounts">
                <IndexRoute component={AccountPage}/>
                <Route path="add" component={AccountAdd} />
                <Route path="detail/:id" component={AccountDetail} />
            </Route>
            <Route path="contacts">
                <Route path="detail/:id" component={ContactPage}/>
            </Route>
            <Route path="transmissors">
                <Route path="detail/:id" component={TransmissorPage}/>
            </Route>
            <Route path="attends" component={AttendancePage} />
            <Route path="reports" component={ReportPage} />
            <Route path="configs" component={ConfigurationPage} />
        </Route>
        <Route path="*" onEnter={redirect}/>
    </Router>
```

My url url_base/app/accounts works correctly, but my url  url_base/app/accounts/detail/2 appears blank

I did some modifications at my router, before theses changes my url were url_base/accounts and url_base/accounts/detail/2

What is wrong? There is a limit for nested routes?

Comment: Can you please show your AccountDetail component??

Answer (score 0):

My error was at the component that calls AccountDetail component:

```
<div className="account-table-td-actions-container">
    <Link className="account-table-td-actions-a" to={"/app/accounts/detail/"+ this.props.id}>
        <List svgClass="account-table-td-actions-list" width="24" height="24" />
    </Link>
    <Link className="account-table-td-actions-a" to={"/app/accounts/detail/"+ this.props.id}>                   
        <Edit svgClass="account-table-td-actions-edit" width="24" height="24" />
    </Link>
    <Link className="account-table-td-actions-a" to={"/app/accounts/detail/"+ this.props.id}>
        <Delete svgClass="account-table-td-actions-delete" width="24" height="24" />
    </Link></div>
```

The Link to was wrong, then I set the correct url: /app/accounts/detail/